# I am getting 'remoteurl' error while uploading manifest file in app store

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am creating web add in. i am loading .aspx page in task pane.
when i am uploading it in app store to test in some others system .its giving me error
This app can't be installed. The IconUrl value '~remoteAppUrl/Images/Add-on_64px.png' isn't a correctly formatted URL

how i can test web add in in some others system

```
  <DesktopSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/SaveEmail.aspx"/>
    <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
  </DesktopSettings>
```

Comment: To put your manifest in the store, you app needs to be hosted and accessible at a specific address.  If you just want to share it with other users, you can email them or send them a link to your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

The `SourceLocation` URL and all icon assets must be a valid https address in order to properly install to Exchange.